# Shiny R - table output dependent on choice from dropdown menu

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to add a drop down menu to manipulate my dataframe.

For example,

Assume my df has the columns - a1  a2  a3  b1  b2 c1 c2 c3

and I wanted to add a dropdown menu with choices = list("All", "a", "b", "c") that would filter the table to include all columns, columns that begin with a or begin with b an so on.

Not sure how to go about this. Open to either creating new df's that can be called when a choice is selected or having the df manipulated based on the choice.

Here is some sample code (not my real code):

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("x"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "x", 
                  choices = list("All", "a", "b", "c"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput('x')
    )
  )
))


#dfa <- data.frame(select(df, starts_with("a")))

#dfb <- data.frame(select(df, starts_with("b")))

#dfc <- data.frame(select(df, starts_with("c")))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$x = renderDataTable({

    ?????

    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reactive:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    reactive_df <- reactive({
      if(input$x=="All")
        return df
      else
        return(select(df, starts_with(input$x)))
    }

    output$x <- renderDataTable(reactive_df())

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Very helpful.